# Is Felix Klein approach the same as Arnold on Abel's Theorem?

Tags: proof-explanation

Arnold has a geometric approach to prove Abel's theorem, this is explained in V. B. Alekseev's book [Abel's Theorem in Problems and Solutions: Based on the Lectures of Professor V.I. Arnold](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Abels-Theorem-Problems-Solutions-Professor/dp/9048166098/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=abel%20theorem%20arnold&qid=1602595148&s=books&sr=1-1) . It's quite impressive.

I just found that Felix Klein also has a book on it: [Lectures on the Icosahedron and the Solution of the Fifth Degree](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Lectures-Icosahedron-Solution-Fifth-Degree/dp/1602063060/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=felix%20klein%20lectures%20on&qid=1602595086&s=books&sr=1-2). Is this approach the same as Arnold?

Comment: Thanks. Right now it’s fine.

Comment: @FelixMarin I understand Arnold's method, his book has another translatetion by [Sujit Nair](https://staff.math.su.se/shapiro/Articles/AbelNew.pdf) which I read. I'm not sure on Felix Klein's.

Comment: Book at [this link](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-1-4020-2187-9/mode/2up)

Comment: It's not the same approach. Klein's is less elementary and algebraic, Arnold's is more elementary and geometric.